# java client server chat transferred files not received properly

Tags: java

I have my client server chat

Client sends files and server receives them. But, the problem is that, i don't think that files are received properly because when i check the size of the files i see the difference is halfed for some reasons!

I am using GUI to browse for files in the client side, and then i'm sending a command to the server to know that the client is sending a file. But it is not working

Here is the client and server

```
public void sendFiles(String file)  {
        try {
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = null;
            outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());

            System.out.println("Sending file...");

            if (outToClient != null) {
                File myFile = new File( file );
                byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];

                FileInputStream fis = null;

                fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

                    this.out.println("SF");
                    bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
                    this.out.flush();
                    outToClient.flush();
                    outToClient.close();

                    System.out.println("File sent!");
                    return;
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Server

```
public void recvFile() {

        try {

            byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
            int bytesRead;
            InputStream is = null;

            is = sock.getInputStream();

            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            if (is != null) {

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream("/Users/Documents/Received.png");
                    bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                    bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);

                    do {
                        baos.write(aByte);
                        bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
                    } while (bytesRead != -1);

                    bos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                    bos.flush();
                    bos.close();
                    //                   clientSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Do exception handling
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Can someone help me with this issue? As i don't know how to properly send and receive files

Thank you

Comment: Deyaa, don't remove the code from your question. That's what the question is *about.* Removing it makes the question completely valueless. You can always delete the entire *question* if you wish.

Comment: In addition, it is very unfair to @EJP to delete the question, when he's spent time and effort to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You are using two copy techniques, and they are both wrong.

First:

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[(int) myFile.length()];
bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
outToClient.write(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
```

Here you are assuming:

1. That the file fits into memory.
2. That the file length fits into an `int`.
3. That `read()` fills the buffer.

None of these assumptions is valid.

Second:

```
byte[] aByte = new byte[1];
bytesRead = is.read(aByte, 0, aByte.length);
do {
    baos.write(aByte);
    bytesRead = is.read(aByte);
} while (bytesRead != -1);
```

Here you are:

1. Using a ridiculously small buffer of one byte.
2. Writing an extra byte if the file length is zero.
3. Using a `do/while` where the situation naturally calls for a `while` (as 99.99% of situations do), and therefore:
4. Using two `read()` calls, and only correctly checking the result of one of them.
5. Pointlessly using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, which, as above, assumes the file fits into memory and that its size fits into an `int`. It also pointlessly adds latency.

Throw them both away and use this, at both ends:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
int count;
while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
{
    out.write(buffer, 0, count);
}
```

where:

- `in` is a `FileInputStream` in the case of sending the file, or the socket input stream in the case of receiving the file.
- `out` is a `FileOutputStream` in the case of receiving the file, or the socket output stream in the case of sending the file